# issue with "if else" statement in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, if-statement, webdriver

Here is my problem. I have 2 dropdowns on page. First is visible and another is initially hidden. If you select specific value from dropdown1 then dropdown2 will become visible - in this case I need to select value from dropdown2 as well. For some reason when I pick values from dropdown1 which doesn't trigger dropdown2 to appear my test fails with "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted" error. It works only when I pick value from dropdown1 that WILL trigger dropdown2 to appear. Not sure what's wrong with my script. I also tried .isEmpty, but had same issue.

```
    //select value from dropdown1
    new Select(driver.findElement(CONTACT)).selectByVisibleText(strContact);

    //if dropdown2 becomes visible then select value from dropdown2
    if(!driver.findElement(PREF_TIME).isDisplayed()){

         new Select(driver.findElement(PREF_TIME)).selectByVisibleText("Evening");

     //if dropdown2 is not visible then move to next object and continue with test
     }else{

          new Select(driver.findElement(HEAR)).selectByVisibleText(strHear);

     }
```

Comment: What's the HTML markup of the two dropdowns?

Comment: dropdown1: <option value="Please select" class="ng-binding" disabled="" selected="">Please select</option>                <!-- ngRepeat: option in options --><option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in options" value="Phone Preferred">Phone Preferred</option><!-- end ngRepeat: option in options --><option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in options" value="Email Preferred">Email Preferred</option><!-- end ngRepeat: option in options -->

Comment: dropdown2: <option value="Please select" class="ng-binding" disabled="" selected="">Please select</option>                <!-- ngRepeat: option in options --><option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in options" value="Morning">Morning</option><!-- end ngRepeat: option in options --><option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in options" value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option><!-- end ngRepeat: option in options --><option class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in options" value="Evening">Evening</option><!-- end ngRepeat: option in options -->

Comment: The comments for your `if` statement and the actual statement are backwards? if element is visible (comment) is followed by an 'if .isDisplayed() = false`. Typos?

Comment: @Mark - thank you! It was backward and I didn't realize that. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to wait some time until the second select appear on the screen - that is why you are getting this error (Selenium does not see the second `select` tag - all these options happen to fast)

You can use Java's Thread class:

```
Thread.sleep(800);
```

Another thing is selecting option from `select` element. I think it's a good idea to choose an option from list:

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath(yourXpathGoesHere));
Select dropDown = new Select(select);  
List<WebElement> options = dropDown.getOptions();
options.get(1).click();
```

You can easily select element by xpath; xpath can be found via web dev tools built in your browser. But the best way is to find elements by id attribute - this way you are sure you get the right element because there might be only one element on the page with given ID.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But when second select appears on page it finds it well without any waits. As you can see it's part of my If statement. I think the issue I'm having is it never gets to Else statement after If statement gets executed. So for cases when the second select is NOT showing up my script gets stuck on first visible select.